# python url unquote followed by unicode decode

Tags: url-encoding, python-unicode

I have a unicode string like `'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'` and I want to decode this string.
I used `urllib.unquote_plus(str)` but it works wrong.

- expected : `çöasd+fjkls%asd`
- result : `Ã§Ã¶asd fjkls%asd`

double coded utf-8 characters(`%C3%A7` and `%C3%B6`) are decoded wrong.
My python version is 2.7 under a linux distro.
What is the best way to get expected result?

Comment: Please do your attempted helpers a favour and publish the result of executing `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: Indeed, the decoding itself is probably working OK, but the reencoding for console display may be having problems.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have 3 or 4 or 5 problems ... but `repr()` and `unicodedata.name()` are your friends; they unambiguously show you exactly what you have got, without the confusion engendered by people with different console encodings communicating the results of `print fubar`.

Summary: either (a) you start with a unicode object and apply the unquote function to that or (b) you start off with a str object and your console encoding is not UTF-8.

If as you say you start off with a unicode object:

```
>>> s0 = u'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'
>>> print repr(s0)
u'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'
```

this is an accidental nonsense. If you apply `urllibX.unquote_YYYY()` to it, you get another nonsense unicode object (`u'\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb6asd+fjkls%asd'`) which would cause your shown symptoms when printed. You should convert your original unicode object to a str object immediately:

```
>>> s1 = s0.encode('ascii')
>>> print repr(s1)
'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'
```

then you should unquote it:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> s2 = urllib2.unquote(s1)
>>> print repr(s2)
'\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb6asd+fjkls%asd'
```

Looking at the first 4 bytes of that, it's encoded in UTF-8. If you do `print s2`, it will look OK if your console is expecting UTF-8, but if it's expecting ISO-8859-1 (aka latin1) you'll see your symptomatic rubbish (first char will be A-tilde). Let's park that thought for a moment and convert it to a Unicode object:

```
>>> s3 = s2.decode('utf8')
>>> print repr(s3)
u'\xe7\xf6asd+fjkls%asd'
```

and inspect it to see what we've actually got:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> for c in s3[:6]:
...     print repr(c), unicodedata.name(c)
...
u'\xe7' LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
u'\xf6' LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS
u'a' LATIN SMALL LETTER A
u's' LATIN SMALL LETTER S
u'd' LATIN SMALL LETTER D
u'+' PLUS SIGN
```

Looks like what you said you expected. Now we come to the question of displaying it on your console. Note: don't freak out when you see "cp850"; I'm doing this portably and just happen to be doing this in a Command Prompt on Windows.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp850'
>>> print s3
çöasd+fjkls%asd
```

Note: the unicode object was explicitly encoded using sys.stdout.encoding. Fortunately all the unicode characters in `s3` are representable in that encoding (and cp1252 and latin1).

Comment: I didn't have the same problem as OP but your clear walkthrough of encoding and decoding helped me immediately get working what I haven't been able to from reading quite a bit of documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Using either `unquote` or `unquote_plus` will give you a byte string. If you want a Unicode string then you have to decode the byte string to unicode:

```
>>> print(urllib.unquote_plus('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd').decode('utf8'))
çöasd fjkls%asd
>>>
```

Compared with:

```
>>> print(urllib.unquote_plus('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'))
Ã§Ã¶asd fjkls%asd
>>>
```

Note that your input string must be a byte string: if you pass unicode to `unquote/unquote_plus` then you'll get a bit of a mess. If this is the case then encode it first:

```
>>> print(urllib.unquote_plus(u'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd'.encode('ascii')).decode('utf8'))
çöasd fjkls%asd
```

Comment: +1 for the `urllib.unquote_plus(u'äö'.encode('ascii')).decode('utf8')` I needed this in Django 1.7 to decode a [file upload name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/uploads/).

Answer (score 0):

Try `urllib2` once more:

```
print urllib2.unquote('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply  i have already tried it and it gave me the same result. do you have any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd' - this is not a unicode string.

This is a url-encoded string. Use urllib2.unquote() instead.

Comment: this is the results :  `>>> import urllib2  
>>> print urllib2.unquote('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')  
Ã§Ã¶asd+fjkls%asd`  my python version is 2.7 can be the problem because of version differences ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a double problem: your string is unicode encoded and contains caracter urlencoded. Some match. You can normalize your string to ascci to be sure it won't be interpreted incorrectly:

```
>>> s = '%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd' # ascii string
>>> print urllib2.unquote(s) # works as expected
çöasd+fjkls%asd
>>> s = u'%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd' # unicode string
>>> print urllib2.unquote(s) # decode stuff that it shouldn't
Ã§Ã¶asd+fjkls%asd
>>> print urllib2.unquote(s.encode('ascii')) # encode the unicode string to ascii: works!
çöasd+fjkls%asd
```

Comment: i really think something is wrong with my python version because i copied your code but result was 'Ã§Ã¶asd+fjkls%asd' again. even though i have already investigated alternatives, do you know any other module i can use instead of urllib

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be Python. But to be honest, I'm running out or rational explanations :-) Did you tried voodoo ? Have you tried it directly in the Python shell ? If no, you may want to define the encoding of your file on the top of it. What is your OS? I'm guessing windows since has a lot of encoding issues.

Comment: voodoo? a little outdated; try a tambourine (http://www.elcomsoft.com/tambourine.html?r1=pr&r2=april1) or (much better) the `repr()` built-in function.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `unquote_plus` method which is taking `space` into account and converting to `+`. Just use `unquote` method and you should be fine.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print urllib.unquote('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')
çöasd+fjkls%asd
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')
çöasd fjkls%asd
```

Comment: actually, what I expected is the second output but i am doing exactly the same thing and here is my results;  `>>> import urllib  
>>> print urllib.unquote('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')  
Ã§Ã¶asd+fjkls%asd  
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus('%C3%A7%C3%B6asd+fjkls%25asd')
Ã§Ã¶asd fjkls%asd`

Comment: Encoding your string to ascii ( `s.encode('ascii')`) and then using quote_plus. It should do.